# Downside of using my own Autofac LifetimeScope in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I am writing MVC UI wrapper reusing legacy core libraries that were written down for desktop edition using Autofac for DI. The problem I am facing is, core libraries are working with Lifetime scope that I can't change while MVC requires InstancePerRequest.

So what happens is, in MVC, if I register my services for InstancePerRequest scope, they get disposed by core libraries before request completes. It makes MVC application unhappy.
I tried using LifeTimeScope for all services in MVC app too. Since Lifetime scope is shorter than Request life, it appears to work in MVC.

Is there any downside in this approach?

**Note:** In legacy code all the time services are being resolved manually, instead of being injected through constructor. Like:

```
using (var scope = IocContainer.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    var service = scope.Resolve<IMyService>();
    return service.FindAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC will work with `InstancePerLifetimeScope` for services [as noted in the documentation about sharing registrations across apps that have and apps that don't have request scopes](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#sharing-dependencies-across-apps-without-requests).

I think there are going to be potentially two gotchas in your approach to creating your own lifetime scope. Whether you can live with them is very much app specific so you'll have to judge for yourself.

**Problem 1: Early Disposal**

In your example you show a factory or service `IMyService` being resolved, doing some work, and returning that work. At the end of the `using` statement the owning lifetime scope is getting disposed. That means `IMyService` will be disposed (if it's `IDisposable`) and any dependencies that `IMyService` requires will also be disposed. In the case of things like database contexts or connections, that well could mean the return value becomes invalid because you won't be able to update the values or read additional data against a disposed connection.

**Problem 2: Singleton/Sharing Issues**

Lifetime scopes are sometimes used to isolate units of work or sets of components that need shared context. For example, in MVC you only have one instance of the controller for the whole request - no matter how many times you resolve the controller object, for that request it'll be the same instance. You might see a similar thing with database connections - one connection from the pool allocated for an entire request lifetime.

By creating your own lifetime scope you are also creating a sort of logical unit of work. Any dependencies for `IMyService` will *not* be shared with the rest of the MVC request. In fact, it's more like that tiny lifetime scope *is its own request* or its own unit of work. No overlap.

**General Resolution**

As noted in the [doc I linked to earlier](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#sharing-dependencies-across-apps-without-requests), register things as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` if they need to be used in both MVC and non-MVC contexts and just let the MVC request semantics handle spinning up and disposal of scopes if possible.

If that won't work, it'll be up to you and your app code to figure out if you can live with the issues here or if you need to address them. If you need to address them, that, too, will be app specific so there isn't "guidance" to provide - you're on your own for that.